# Given data in the units $\text{C}/\text{min}$ and $\text{g}$, is it possible to arrive at $((\text{C})/\text{g})⁄\text{min}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given data in the units $\text{C}/\text{min}$ and $\text{g}$, is it possible to arrive at this unit $((\text{C})/\text{g})⁄\text{min}$? If so, which mathematical operation to use?

I tried $\text{g}\times \text{C}/\text{min}$ and $(\text{C}/\text{min})/\text{g}$, but neither seem to arrive to the desired unit.

Comment: $(C/g)/min = C/(g \times min) = (C/min)/g$. So divide your first quantity by the second.

Comment: $\frac {\frac Cg}{min}=\frac {\frac C{min}}g$.

Comment: So if you have $x \frac C{min}$ and $yg$ then $\frac {x\frac C{min}}{yg} = \frac xy \frac {\frac Cq}{min}$

Answer (score 1):

It is often helpful to remember that division is nothing but multiplying by the reciprocal.

You start off with units in C/min and g and desire C/g/min. C/g/min is nothing more than $C×\frac{1}{g}×\frac{1}{min}$. Your initial units were C/min and g so you can multiply C/min by the reciprocal of g to get your answer.